# count no of entries in different xml tags

Tags: xml, bash, awk, grep

I have a XML format file with Added and Deleted tags.which will have many category except Birds and Humans.so below xml file will have many entries with different categories and many values in them as below

```
<xml version=1.0>
   <NameCategory="Birds">
       <Added>
         <value name="Duck" count="1"></value>
         <value name="Dove" count="2"></value>
       </Added>
       <Deleted>
         <value name="crow" count="1"></value>
         <value name="crane" count="10"></value>
       </Deleted>
   </NameCategory>
   <NameCategory="Humans">
         <value name="john" count="1"></value>
   </NameCategory>
</xml>
```

So here i need to count total no. of entries for each category in tags like as

```
Total No Of Added Birds=2
Total No Of Deleted Birds=2
Total No Of Added Humans=1
```

Comment: your xml is not well formed.  Why do you think text based solutions will be better than specialized xml based tools?

Comment: Yeegh. The header was obviously broken, and the lack of a root element was an issue, but I missed `<Element="Attribute">` and the invalid use of single quotes on first glance -- this *really* isn't something that can be fed through XML-aware tools, cutting off a large set of otherwise-possible answers. @missi, perhaps you might edit this to specify "XML-like" syntax (if your real documents aren't actually XML), or edit it to actually parse?

Comment: Your file is still not valid XML. Paste Your file there to check its syntax: https://validator.w3.org/#validate-by-input

Answer (score 2):

With xmlstarlet and this fixed XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <fixed NameCategory="Birds">
    <Added>
      <value name="Duck" count="1"/>
      <value name="Dove" count="2"/>
    </Added>
    <Deleted>
      <value name="crow" count="1"/>
      <value name="crane" count="10"/>
    </Deleted>
  </fixed>
  <fixed NameCategory="Humans">
    <value name="john" count="1"/>
  </fixed>
</root>
```

Show added birds:

```
xmlstarlet select --template --value-of "//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Birds']/Added/value/@name" --nl file.xml
```

Output:

```
Duck
Dove
```

---

Count added birds:

```
xmlstarlet select --template --value-of "count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Birds']/Added/value/@name)" file.xml
```

Output:

```
2
```

---

Count added and deleted birds and humans with one command:

```
xmlstarlet select --template \
   --value-of "count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Birds']/Added/value/@name)" --nl \
   --value-of "count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Birds']/Added/value/@name)" --nl \
   --value-of "count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Humans']/value/@name)" --nl file.xml
```

Output:

```
2
2
1
```

---

With prefixed Text:

```
xmlstarlet select --template \
   --value-of "concat('Total No Of Added Birds=',count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Birds']/Added/value/@name))" --nl \
   --value-of "concat('Total No Of Deleted Birds=',count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Birds']/Deleted/value/@name))" --nl \
   --value-of "concat('Total No Of Added Humans=',count(//root/fixed[@NameCategory='Humans']/value/@name))" --nl file.xml
```

Output:

```
Total No Of Added Birds=2
Total No Of Deleted Birds=2
Total No Of Added Humans=1
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`

Comment: Nice answer.   Note that the `xml` root element was almost certainly a botched XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`).   If restored to that, there'd have to be a replacement XML root element, though.

Comment: @kjhughes: Thank you. I fixed this.